# Using the Asana API, how can I create a project based on a custom template?

Tags: php, asana, asana-api

I would like to programmatically add projects, based on a default custom template we have already made in Asana. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

verheul, sorry for the delay - we had a little bit of connection issues in tying together all our channels.

We don't have any API feature for programmatically using an Asana template to create a project, but I've added this request to our API backlog. The best workaround that I can think to offer you right now is to have your program copy the template itself; that is, create a new project, then for each task in the template, create a new task just like it in the new project. In essence, write the template copy functionality that uses the Asana template as the source.

Our [API documentation](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference) should be of some help here, and although this is a bit of a workaround, hopefully this will help you get moving!